# Obj-C, why is my UIActionSheet Cancel button hard to tap?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiactionsheet

I've noticed in my app that my cancel button is hard to tap, it seem like the hit area is not in the center.

How do I fix this ?

Heres my code...

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"" 
  delegate:dg 
  cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil
  otherButtonTitles: @"Help Pages", @"Tutorial", 
  @"Feedback / Questions ", @"Facebook Group", @"About", nil];

actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackOpaque;
[actionSheet setTag:CommonUIActionSheetHelp];
[actionSheet showInView:vw];
[actionSheet release];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

agree whit Ravin answer and you can try

```
[actionSheet showInView:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];
```

it can help also

Answer (score 6):

I think your problem lies in the `[actionSheet showInView:vw];`, perhaps you are using tabBarController/toolBar in you application(at bottom), this error occurs at that time.

you should use either `showFromToolbar` or `showFromTabBar` as per your design. If your design is different then please mention it.(if no tabBar/toolBar there).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem in iOS 8, using `UIAlertController` with style `UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet`.

The problem is that the first tap on the action sheet is ignored.

Turned out it got to do with my text field's keyboard interfering with the touches.

The fix is to dismiss the keyboard first, then present the action sheet.

```
[textfield resignFirstResponder];
[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```